# Updating Data Set query after parameter input in BIRT

Tags: javascript, mysql, birt

How can I change or update a data set's query after a parameter has been passed in BIRT report designing?

Detailing:

I've got a query that looks like this:

```
WHERE ?
```

That parameter marker can hold different values, after user input parameter, it would look like this  e.g.:

```
WHERE column_name = 1
```

or

```
WHERE column_name = 2
```

or even

```
WHERE column_name IN (1,2)
```

I created a Report Parameter(RP) for that Data Set Parameter(DSP) and after trying for hours, I couldn't get to change it.

I tried:

- Creating all sorts of javascript expressions on both, RP and DSP
- Creating a RP that would change the value of the first RP and back to previous step
- Editing the Property Binding, though I couldn't figure it out how exactly it should be done.
  Just to make it clear, I'm designing a report and not integrating the runtime to an existing application.
  I hope this is clear enough, I'm still editing the question so if you need more information just let me know.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that you are on an Oracle DB (other systems may behave differently) you should be aware that a bind variable (in JDBC speech: the question mark) can replace a *scalar value* only, e.g. a string or a number.

But you want something like a *list* of numbers as input.
Thus a bind variable won't help you in this case.

Probably the easiest way to achieve what you want is this:

In your query, write:

```
WHERE column_name in (1) -- $REPLACE_THIS$
```

Note that I am using a comment in the query as a marker.
Then, in the query's `beforeOpen` event, modify the query text like this:

```
// construct a comma-separated string representation of your list
// based on your report parameter (exercise left to the reader)
// var replacement = my_to_sql_csv(params["my_report_parameter"].value);

// for demonstration use:
var replacement = "1,2";

// modify the `IN` expression inside the SQL
this.queryText = this.queryText.replaceAll("(1) -- $REPLACE_THIS$", "(" + replacement + ")";
```

That's it.

Comment: I think I didn't read your question precisely. It seems that your RP already contains a WHERE expression like "columnA like 'Blah' and columnB in (1,2,3)". In that case, write WHERE 1=0 -- $REPLACE_THIS$ in your query and change the script code accordingly.

Comment: A similar question has been answered in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18607429/how-to-create-a-birt-dataset-that-accepts-multiple-csv-values-that-it-can-be-u/18608665#18608665, as I saw a minute ago. Please note the comment there about the risk of SQL injection attack. That means, be sure to correctly escape all characters that have a special meaning in SQL.

Comment: Thanks for your help, your last comment sent me to the right direction.