# How to add a parameter to a SQL query?

Tags: birt, maximo

I would like to add a dynamic parameter in addition to parameters from Maximo inside SQL query.

Something like that :

```
select * 
from workorder a 
where params["where"] or a.parent = :Param
```

with `params["where"]` with wonum='1234' and `:Param = '1234'`

Is it possible with Birt to get wonum value and put it also to `:Param` ?

Or maybe another way ?

Thanks

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28070809/updating-data-set-query-after-parameter-input-in-birt for the principle of a solution.

Comment: thanks. I will take a look !

Comment: I tried to add log to "beforeOpen" to see my query before modify it as it is explained to the link but query is null. Is it normal ?

Comment: this.queryText contains the SQL statement. Obviously you did something wrong. You should probably post your beforeOpen script...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok I solved my problem.
I created a JDBC data source and I have access to a new sort of data set.
I can put my query in this data set and I have access to "beforeopen" and my query is not null.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

open is like that (query is more complicated so I simplify it):

```
maximoDataSet = MXReportDataSetProvider.create(this.getDataSource().getName(), this.getName());
maximoDataSet.open();

var sqlText = new String();
sqlText = "select column1, column2 as woParent, etc... from workorder where  " + params["where"] + " or woParent=:param";

maximoDataSet.setQuery(sqlText);
```

beforeopen is like that(just to see the query) :

```
importPackage( Packages.java.io );
out = new PrintWriter( new FileWriter( "c:/birteaump.log", true ) );
out.println( "\nMy Query: " + this.queryText);
out.close();
```

I had some code to manipulate :param to replace it with wonum but this.queryText is null.
I'm a newbie to birt report maybe I have to think differently to solve my problem.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I used Birt 3.7.1. I saw in a video that we can add a query in a dataset's dialog box. But with my report I only have "scripted data set" when I use the "new data set" button.

Is it possible that my query is null in "beforeopen" is in relation with that ?

If I create another sort of datasource, I will have acces to another sort of dataset ?

thanks