# Javascript in either property binding or Query in Birt

Tags: javascript, mysql, birt, property-binding

Can I include javascript in the property binding Query Text field of a BIRT report Data Set?
The reason why I want to do this is to select a query depending on a report parameter passed by the user.

Comment: Dominique already answered this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, for instance you can do this in this field:

```
var param=params["myParameter"].value;
if (param==1){
  "select code,label from tableA";
}else{
  "select code,label from tableB";
}
```

However this makes reports more difficult to maintain. Most of the time it is a better practice to modify an existing queryText from "beforeOpen" method of the dataset, by replacing keywords such explained in [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18607429/how-to-create-a-birt-dataset-that-accepts-multiple-csv-values-that-it-can-be-u/18608665#18608665)

Comment: Replacing keywords, as you suggested and explained, is much more elegant, indeed.